# Nx Angular Lint Error after TSLint to ESLint Migration

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I'm very new to [Nx](https://nx.dev/) and today I tried to migrate all our Angular apps from TSLint to ESLint. What I did was to run the following command for each app:

```
nx g convert-tslint-to-eslint --project=SELECTED_PROJECT
```

After the migration I ran *npm install* and then *npm run lint*. But each time I run the linter, I get the following error without any detailed information:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')

The project specs:

- Angular v12.2.13
- Nx v12.10.1

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the origin on the problem.
The issue is related with this ESLint rule:

```
"indent": [
      "error",
      4,
      {
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
```

Have no idea why it's breaking with this rule. For now I removed it and using the overrides to apply this rule:

```
"@typescript-eslint/indent": [
          "error",
          4,
          {
            "FunctionDeclaration": {
              "parameters": "first"
            },
            "FunctionExpression": {
              "parameters": "first"
            }
          }
        ],
```

If anyone finds a better way to solve this issue, please let me know.